# How can I join two bezier curves at a 90 degree angle?

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a bezier curve object, and I'm trying to complete the loop with one final segment. The problem is that the two ends are both curves, and when I try to connect them using F they produce a weird curved pattern. I can't change the handle type without disrupting the existing curves. How can I draw a straight line between these two points?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the top handle of the top control point and press <kbd>V</kbd> > *Vertor*:

[image]

Select the bottom control point and press <kbd>V</kbd> > *Vertor* again:

[image]

Fill between the 2 control points, you should end up with this:

[image]

[image: th]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.

Comment: The vertices on curves are called control points. And the menu option for the handle type is _Vector_, not _Vertex_. 

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Oops you're right, I've edited

Comment: How can I merge two control points when they are both curves? I'll add an image of what I mean to the question.

Comment: @user5104897 the second one seems more difficult, maybe ask a new question with this one

Comment: @moonboots OK, I've spun it off as a separate question.

Comment: @user5104897 It doesn't look like there's any quick answer for your second shape, you'll need to fiddle with your curve